# Set UINavigationBar height like in iOS 7 calendar app

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, ios7

I need a NavigationBar like in the calendar in iOS 7.

I have noticed that the NavigationBar does not have any blur behind it.

[image: Calendar app iOS7]

when going back from one detail view. It's just the "main" `NavigationBar` that is "normal".

[image: Calendar app iOS7]

Anyone have any idea how to do this?

I have tried to do this:

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 88)];
```

But this would move the title and the buttons down 44px.

I have another idea to add another navigation bar under the `navigationController.navigationBar`, but then I have a line under the first navigation bar. Anyone knows how to remove this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I fixed it!

I placed a other NavigationBar under the "main" NavigationBar. Removed the "main" NavigationBars shadow line.

Remove the NavigationBar translucent and set the background color to 97% white. (it's standard). If translucent is YES it would look strange when content is behind .

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTranslucent:NO];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBarTintColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.97 alpha:1]];
[NavigationBarExtension setTranslucent:NO];
[NavigationBarExtension setBarTintColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.97 alpha:1]];
```

Code to remove the line (do this in viewWillAppear: because if you push a other view controller the line must come back)

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    for (UIView *view in self.navigationController.navigationBar.subviews) {
        if ([view isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"_UINavigationBarBackground")]) {
            for (UIView *view2 in view.subviews) {
                if ([view2 isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]] && view2.frame.size.height < 1) {
                    [view2 setHidden:YES];
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Code to show the line when pushing a other view controller:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    for (UIView *view in self.navigationController.navigationBar.subviews) {
        if ([view isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"_UINavigationBarBackground")]) {
            for (UIView *view2 in view.subviews) {
                if ([view2 isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]] && view2.frame.size.height < 1) {
                    [view2 setHidden:NO];
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you get this into the app store? You're accessing private classes. There's a few other ways to do this as well. You can create a custom navigation bar and adjust the height in the sizeToFit as well as hide the background of a bar by setting the subview of the bar at index 0 to alpha 0 (probably not the safest but it does what you want).

The reason you need to embed another bar is apple has bound the items to the bottom of the bar when you resize it and you now have to proxy all the item settings to the new internal bar with a hidden background.

Comment: I do not have any project using this right now. I will inform you if I publish a app with this API.

Comment: @GustafR did you published the app with the above code? does Apple Approved it? :-)

Comment: @KasunRandika Sorry, but I never published the app so I don't know.

Comment: Apple approved my app that uses this hack in two different spots. But unfortunately this little trick no longer works with iOS 11. It's time to find a different way to pull this off.